# How many respondents indicated that they work on 'MySQL' only?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that was taken from a survey. I have two columns: the number ID of the respondent and the database they worked with.

```
    Respondent  DatabaseWorkedWith
0   4   MySQL
1   4   SQLite
2   9   DynamoDB
3   9   PostgreSQL
4   9   SQLite
... ... ...
31370   25137   MySQL
31371   25138   PostgreSQL
31372   25141   Microsoft SQL Server
31373   25141   Redis
31374   25142   PostgreSQL

31375 rows × 2 columns
```

The question is on the title. I would like to count the number of respondents that only have MySQL on the second column. I'm not sure if I should use unique, groupby or another method.

Thanks!

Comment: Where you say "only", you mean that the rows with the same `Respondent` number correspond to the same respondent? So you want to find rows that have `MySQL`, such that there *also aren't* other rows with the same `Respondent`? Yeah, that does sound like you want to consider the rows in groups according to the `Respondent`, which is what `groupby` does. What happened when you tried just using `.groupby` and looking at the result? Did it seem like something that got you closer to a solution?

Comment: Hi @KarlKnechtel! Yes, you are correct! I want to retrieve the number of respondents that only have MySQL, meaning respondent #1 won't have one row with MySQL and one row with MongoDB. Using `groupby` and `count` I can see the number of languages for each respondent.

Comment: Okay. For the respondents you're interested in, the ones who used only MySQL, how many languages did they use? Do you know how to filter the groupby result to get those  respondents? Then  you can filter them again according to who actually responded with MySQL, yeah? Another thing you could try doing is combining all the names of the databases they used, and looking for combinations that just have MySQL in them.

Comment: You might also want to refer to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that may not be the most practical one, but it worked.

First, I created a data frame summing the column 'DatabaseWorkedWith':

```
resp_sum = df.groupby('Respondent').sum()

Respondent DatabaseWorkedWith
4   MySQLSQLite
9   DynamoDBPostgreSQLSQLite
13  CouchbaseDynamoDBFirebaseMySQL
16  MongoDBMicrosoft SQL ServerMySQL
17  MongoDBPostgreSQL
... ...
25136   Microsoft SQL Server
25137   MySQL
25138   PostgreSQL
25141   Microsoft SQL ServerRedis
25142   PostgreSQL

10945 rows × 1 column
```

Using the new data frame, I counted by the column 'DatabaseWorkedWith' where the value was 'MySQL.'

```
resp_sum[resp_sum['DatabaseWorkedWith']=='MySQL'].count()

DatabaseWorkedWith    474
dtype: int64
```

If you guys could present a more elegant solution, I would appreciate it!
Thanks!

Comment: This does run the risk of encountering someone who claimed to have worked, say, with both "MyS" and "QL". I'm pretty sure there is a way to get a list of the values in the group rather than concatenating the strings, but I don't actually use Pandas regularly; I'm just good (I think) at telling people how to solve problems and use search engines and documentation.

Comment: Indeed, there is this risk, @KarlKnechtel! I will try to find a better solution and post it! Thanks for your support, though!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which can do the work.
You can drop all the rows with duplicated values in Column 'Respondent', then filter the DatabaseWorkedWith with MySQL.

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DWpT.png)